# How to define the type of generic aggregation of function handler results

Tags: typescript, types

I have something like a generator function that processes an object based on generic input (processors). I want to learn how to type the `processors` and `addProcessors`, so that the result is also typed. Please refer to the sample code for more explanation:

```js
function configure() {
  // I'm using a complex and nested set here
  const config = {
    root: true,
    basic: true,
    value: 10,
  };

  const processors = [ // list of processors
    // default return type is `BaseConfig`
    function(data) {
      // if passed config, result would be: { isRoot: true, isBasic: true, value: 50 }
      return {
        isRoot: data.root,
        isBasic: data.basic,
        value: data.value * 5
      };
    }
  ];

  return {
    addProcessor(handler) { // how to type that?
      processors.push(handler);
      return this;
    },

    done() { // return type should be "BaseType & all processor types)
      // Merging is different,
      // but I want to call all processors
      // and merge their results into a single object
      return Object.assign({}, ...processors.map((p) => p(config)));
    }
  }
}
```

The usage would be something like:

```js
const res = configure()
  .addProcessor(function(data) {
    return {
      isBasic: false,
      value: data.value * 10,
    }
  })
  .done();

// res would look like: { isRoot: true, isBasic: false, value: 100 }
// I want to make res generically typed
```

So the question is - how do I use TS types so that when using `res`, it shows not only the `BaseConfig` types (which contain the values from the default processor, which I have strictly typed), but also the ones that I have generically added? They would have their own types/interfaces, but the base functionality cannot know about them, so a simple union won't work.

What I mean as a sample result:

```
const processor = (): ExtendedConfig => {}
done(): BaseConfig & ExtendedConfig
```

I know a solution for a basic use case like that is to use `as const`. But that works for simple inputs/outputs. My input is a method, and I can chain and have many of those inputs, which I aggregate at the end.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Ideally you'd make this a [mre] including definitions for `BaseConfig` and any other type whose name you'd like to see in the output.

Comment: Given your example code [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w22pzw) shows how I'd give it types.  But I'm skeptical; you had `add` in there instead of `push`, so there's no way you tested the runtime behavior before posting this, leading me to wonder if your implementation actually does what you want after I fixed that.  If it's right, I'd be happy to write up an answer explaining; if not, what specifically am I missing?

Comment: Hey @jcalz, thanks for the playground! It's obvious from the above it's an excerpt from what I'm actually doing, that's why the mistake. But you got the main problem exactly right, and the result seems to work well (at least in the playground :D). I'd be happy if you write an answer. The code seems self-explanatory, but a few more details never hurt :) Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the types

```
interface BaseConfig {
  isRoot: boolean;
  isBasic: boolean;
  value: number;
}

interface Config {
  root: boolean;
  basic: boolean;
  value: number;
}
```

We can give `configure()` the following call signature

```
declare function configure(): Configurator<BaseConfig>;
```

where (for want of a better name) `Configurator<T>` is a recursive [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type defined as

```
interface Configurator<T> {
  addProcessor<U>(
    handler: (config: Config) => U): Configurator<T & U>;
  done(): T
}
```

Let's explore what that means.  A `Configurator<T>` has a `done()` method which returns a value of type `T`.  It also has a generic `addProcessor()` method that takes a callback `handler` of type `(config: Config) => U` for some `U`, and returns a `Configurator<T & U>`.  So when you call `addProcessor()` on a `Configurator<T>`, you get a new `Configurator` whose `done()` method returns the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of `T` (the current `done()` return type) and `U` (the bit added by the `handler`).

And when you run `configure()`, you get a value of type `Configurator<BaseConfig>`.  Let's test that:

```
const res = configure()
  .addProcessor(function (data) {
    return {
      isBasic: false,
      value: data.value * 10,
      helloGoodbye: data.root
    }
  })
  .done();

/* const res: BaseConfig & {
    isBasic: boolean;
    value: number;
    helloGoodbye: boolean;
} */
```

Looks good.

---

Now let's just make sure the function implementation is as strongly typed as we can make it, keeping in mind that the compiler won't be able to fully verify the logic so we might need to resort to [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to smooth over any worries the compiler has about type safety:

```
function configure() {
  const config: Config = {
    root: true,
    basic: true,
    value: 10,
  };

  const processors: ((config: Config) => unknown)[] = [
    function (data): BaseConfig {
      return {
        isRoot: data.root,
        isBasic: data.basic,
        value: data.value * 5
      };
    }
  ];

  return {
    addProcessor(handler) {
      processors.push(handler);
      return this;
    },

    done() {
      return Object.assign({}, ...processors.map((p) => p(config)));
    }
  } as Configurator<BaseConfig>
}
```

In the above I've [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) `config` as type `Config`, and [annotated](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#return-type-annotations) the first `processors` element as returning type `BaseConfig`, just to be sure we're doing what we expect there.

TypeScript doesn't really have a type for `processors` that would keep track of all possible things pushed to it, so I've annotated it as `Array<(config: Config) => unknown>` which is correct but doesn't even try to understand what the return types are going to be, as [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) accepts anything whatsoever.

Finally, I had to assert `as Configurator<BaseConfig>` for the return value.  Otherwise we'd be trying to get the compiler to understand that `addProcessor()` actually changes the type of `this`, and that `processors.map(p => p(config))` would produce a value of an ordered array of return types for things we haven't been tracking anyway.  This isn't very type safe, but it probably the best we can reasonably do.  As long as you're sure your implementation works right, then at least the issue isn't seen by callers.

And does it work right?  Let's try it:

```
/* const res: BaseConfig & {
    isBasic: boolean;
    value: number;
    helloGoodbye: boolean;
} */
console.log(res);
/* {
  "isRoot": true,
  "isBasic": false,
  "value": 100,
  "helloGoodbye": true
}   */
```

Looks good, that's compatible with the type the compiler inferred for `res`.  One more test:

```
const r2 = configure()
  .addProcessor(data => ({ abc: data.value.toFixed(2) }))
  .addProcessor(data => ({ def: data.basic ? "yes" : "no" }))
  .addProcessor(data => ({ ghi: data.root }))
  .done();

/* const r2: BaseConfig & 
  { abc: string; } & 
  { def: string; } & 
  { ghi: boolean; } 
*/

console.log(r2);
/* {
  "isRoot": true,
  "isBasic": true,
  "value": 50,
  "abc": "10.00",
  "def": "yes",
  "ghi": true
} */
```

Also works as expected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ssl=76&ssc=23&pln=75&pc=16#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-gCPnW5A7AoQIoJDDNFoHAVRJU6yEgXAAdxAXWBaN6ILl2t1+sNFSycTgqylNItwagEDAMRAGWD9Jo9BdCybADpnWAY-3BMJXCOwHBRz7RFP+6GfI2F6P1+rkABWOVUHTzI8CBFxqid7tQXvt5DZPIptNQCpchrQc2HpNP1kYUc7RQMBqV96kaLoT3pK8eyJGoaAgnQvTlRYQDNPsOy7aCflYAArCA9VHTARCIEAKlIBDkFHSjk2ZVNf1HdQ4B2CoKh2JUmONbounAuU9CPe8PnFI5JRVA5Ug2fQExtTsPkrDjDjNAQCMZH8EgqGs9QNXsGybT90OvW8vxoWc-XgDgsFXOQFDDedFx3Qkows5AaggDgOFwABxBgslYLYNzHCceIEHQukU5CzTjAlbUTaSWFbB0ZjvIyXD9CQpEcYN11UDQtCgCDnNcjyvJ8nxUocNUNQkq1JAgUc3KICppO4yKLQAIkHGwWtdAMYzaoRks65BTPMgQWvXAao2jEb8rczzcG83yBrdZRAnpCryEk5AoAAJguOTTRWRSHyZFlVM3OA+nSUj71YP0zu3KyaviAAxYAnggLIKi2npgpCqglMfGjn20hcLuQK6sggGAWDu5cEABZAWt8jAWsxBHCxRn7DuUwHWWB87hSuohYOh-ybHRLjQqWFYIsJDbttikSaRmARSGuv1rSgUAiF4dFpmQFmFkhlgOa5nmMWZqhWaJ4A3Gq6RefINaE2q2rcHq7amsJVr2sYRbupGpLfT1z0RrGlg90mqgWrgG6BpaqNR0jSMWp6iGYDtpGXZG6XjYgFaNSAA)

Comment: Hey there! The code was pretty self-explanatory, but thank you for the extra effort to write everything down. I didn't know generics could be recursive. That throws me into another ocean of unknowns :D
Unfortunately, I couldn't make this approach work in my scenario, as we're using JSDoc in a JS project, and I just started adding TS types (using imports) as a first step towards rewriting it. Unable to use `as Configurator<BaseConfig>` makes the result `Configurator<unknown>` and it's losing the base config.
Nevertheless, your solutions works great, so I'd accept the answer in 4 hours :P